# Can ZeroMQ count the number of outstanding messages?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

I am new to ZeroMQ ( on C++ ).?br:
While writing a program with a **`PUB/SUB`** Formal Communication Pattern archetype, I am stuck with a problem.

**Program** :
It's my Project, where I suppose to send as much as possible messages to a **`PUB`**.
For this I used to use a **`ROUTER`** socket-type.

**Problem** :
Receiver is slow, due to which messages are getting queued ( up until reaching the high watermark ) and after that, starts dropping on `SUB` side.

**Looking for** :
I want a method from ZeroMQ ( on C++ ), which tells me a "Count of Messages in Outstanding Queue".

Searched a lot but did not find any answer.
I am looking for any kind of pointer OR help on this.

Comment: ZMQ is an Actor Model system. This means that there is no mechanism for the sender to know when messages are delivered. If you want this you have to have a separate socket for messages back to the publisher from the subscribers, with the messages meaning "please send another message".

Comment: @bazza 13, Thanks for your response. while doing google I found that if send() is called with DONTWAIT flag then it will return -1 in the case of  Queue Full (message delivery failure). Tried same but it's not working. it's always returning size of data. Do you have any idea on this ? even though queue is full but still send() is returning proper value.

Answer (score 2):

Found the Answer. Using 3 parameter under Router type, I was able to solve it.
in zmq.hpp we have send(which goes till router->send method).
at router level we have multiple checks like ( queue is full or packet is not getting delivered, etc)
If we set * router mandator / sendtimeout(-1)/ and send packet with dontwait then zmq send will handle all errors/re-try (including zmq queue full OR HWM hit).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using asynchronous messaging. This means that the sender will have no knowledge of message arrival and/or queuing. Can you try using a static counter, which you'll increment each time the sender sends a message, and another static variable that you'll increment when the receiver gets a message? Taking the difference of these two should tell you how many messages are possibly queued up. It might give you more insight, although this should be experimental as it is not safe. What you should rather focus on is optimizing the SUB so that it does not drop any messages. Check the rate and see if you can work around that. Alternatively, you can create your own buffer, which you'll use to store incoming messages, if your processing causes the latency.